# trying to import excel into python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm still new to python. I'm trying to import an excel doc into python but I get the filenotfounderror
This is what I'm running:

```
import pandas as pd

practiceset = (r'C:\Users\michael\Desktop\Work\Transpo\'Transportation2016.xlsx')

df = pd.read_excel(practiceset)

print (df)
```

The python file is in the same folder as the doc, so I'm confused.

Comment: remove the stray quote in the filename? - `practiceset = (r'C:\Users\michael\Desktop\Work\Transpo\Transportation2016.xlsx')`

Comment: @BransonSmith He's using raw strings, so no, he doesn't need to use two backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

practiceset = (r'C:\Users\michael\Desktop\Work\Transpo\Transportation2016.xlsx')
df = pd.read_excel(practiceset)
print (df)
```

Comment: ahhh I see I did have a stray quote, derp! thank you so much!